# Change the priority of package loading in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, logstash

I'm working on a project based on ELK stack, it's based on [Elk Docker structure](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk), ( you can see my directory structure in the following

[image]

My python scripts are located under *src* , and now for interact with Logstash I tried to use https://github.com/vklochan/python-logstash package, 
installed it with `pip install python-logstash` after I wanted to test it by the sample code provided by `python-logstash` package

```
import logging
import logstash
import sys

host = 'localhost'

test_logger = logging.getLogger('python-logstash-logger')
test_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
test_logger.addHandler(logstash.LogstashHandler(host, 5959, version=1))
# test_logger.addHandler(logstash.TCPLogstashHandler(host, 5959, version=1))

test_logger.error('python-logstash: test logstash error message.')
test_logger.info('python-logstash: test logstash info message.')
test_logger.warning('python-logstash: test logstash warning message.')

# add extra field to logstash message
extra = {
    'test_string': 'python version: ' + repr(sys.version_info),
    'test_boolean': True,
    'test_dict': {'a': 1, 'b': 'c'},
    'test_float': 1.23,
    'test_integer': 123,
    'test_list': [1, 2, '3'],
}
test_logger.info('python-logstash: test extra fields', extra=extra)
```

But faced with **NameError: name 'logstash' is not defined** it seems because I have a `logstash` directory in my root level of the project, **it has higher priority than logstash package which I've been installed by pip**,

**How can I resolve this issue?**

**Notice** :With `print(sys.path)` I've been  sure  the priority of loading is as the following

- the current directory
- your PYTHONPATH
- an installation-dependent default

Comment: Having two modules with the same name is asking for problems.  Rename your module to something besides logstash...

Comment: @StephenRauch thank you for attention, I'm looking for other solutions ( it works but I consider it as my last bullet )

Comment: @StephenRauch actually logstash in my current path is not a python package ( there is not __init__.py in it and just contains logstash Dockerfile )